# MariaDB On delete CASCADE on rows without foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb, cascade

I have a problem I've been cracking my head over the last few days. I have a relational DB (mariaDB), which has two tables. Table A and table B. Table A has a relation with itself, and when one row is deleted, multiple MAY be deleted (via on delete CASCADE). Table B has no relation with table A. I cannot create a relation, as the rows currently present in the tables may or may not have the correct (to enforce this relation) data in it (I have no influence over this).

When I delete a record from table A, I would like the implicitly related data from table B to also be deleted. As a foreign key cannot be created, a on delete CASCADE seems impossible. I thought of a trigger, which would find relevant rows on every delete from table A, however, triggers will not fire on rows deleted by a on delete CASCADE. Meaning that when row X (from table A) gets deleted as a result of a CASCADE, the relevant data from table B will not be deleted.

If I had to summarize this to a question:
Is it possible to delete a row, like on delete CASCADE, without the use of foreign keys or triggers?

Thanks for reading, appreciate it!

Comment: *however, triggers will not fire on rows deleted by a on delete CASCADE.* In the trigger you must perform iterational check from initial row to be deleted, gather all relative rows in B for all relative rows which will be deleted from A, and delete these rows.

Comment: Oeh that seems like a good thing! I will try out, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Which engine does the table use?

Comment: @RickJames InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Akina.

Iterate over rows relevant to the one deleted in the trigger, and then delete all rows relevant to those rows in table B. This works, but I cannot accept my own answer as of yet.